# ubuntu does not show username in ps -ef command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wildfly, ps

I have a wildfly server which is running on Ubuntu as a service. I've done all steps at this site: [WildFly as a Service on Linux](http://developer-should-know.com/post/112230363742/how-to-install-wildfly-as-a-service-on-linux). But the running server can not reach(get permission errors) some root owned files, although I have given root authority to wildfly9_test(adding it sudo and admin group) user. After start service with sudo and then when I run command:

```
ps -ef |grep java
```

the output is:

```
999      27945 27859  9 07:27 pts/1    00:03:08 /usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_79/bin/java -D[Standalone] -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Xms2048m -Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/opt/wildfly-9.0.0.Final_test/standalone/log/server.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/opt/wildfly-9.0.0.Final_test/standalone/configuration/logging.properties -jar /opt/wildfly-9.0.0.Final_test/jboss-modules.jar -mp /opt/wildfly-9.0.0.Final_test/modules org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=/opt/wildfly-9.0.0.Final_test -Djboss.server.base.dir=/opt/wildfly-9.0.0.Final_test/standalone -c standalone.xml
root     28736 27788  0 08:02 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto java
```

Here is `lsb_release -a` command output:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 11.10
Release:        11.10
Codename:       oneiric
```

Why is ps command gets 999(userid) instead of username(wildfly9_test)?

Because of the same problem, does wildfly9_test user not have sudo privileges?

Comment: In your link the user 'wildfly' was never given the sudo privileges. Justto make sure issue this command ```id wildfly``` and see the user's group

Comment: ps only shows the user names up to a certain length, for longer user names it shows the numeric id instad, I guess `wildfly9_test` is simply too long. And adding a user to the `sudo` and `admin` groups doesn't give them automatic access to root owned files but only to files accessible by those groups (and the ability to use `sudo`).

Answer (score 0):

ps only shows the user names up to a certain length, for longer user names it shows the numeric id instad, I guess `wildfly9_test` is simply too long. And adding a user to the `sudo` and `admin` groups doesn't give them automatic access to root owned files but only to files accessible by those groups (and the ability to use `sudo`).
                    – mata